# Create table as select causes error in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

It's strange or I am new? Here is a simple create table as select causing an error in SQL Server 2008.

```
CREATE TABLE [SalesOrderHeader2]
AS
    (SELECT *
     FROM [AW].[sales].SalesOrderHeader)
```

Error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

No error in oracle:

```
create table abc AS 
select * from abc2
```

Comment: I am continually receiving minus points why?

Comment: I want to create new table, you didn't get my question.

Comment: yes agree with you Anoop

Comment: @Muhammad , In sql-server-2008 the syntax is different. Oracle syntax cannot be applied here.

Comment: SQL Server does not support the SQL standard `create table as select`.

Comment: but the duplicate question is not related to my question.

Comment: Yes it is a duplicate

Comment: CREATE TABLE [SalesOrderHeader2] AS (SELECT * FROM [SalesOrderHeader]);

Comment: What about this? is this not follow the SQLSERVER standard syntax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT * INTO New_Table 
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: This is not needed, I need to create a table / New table.

Comment: you wan't to create a table from Existing Table or Simple a new Table

Comment: I want to create table with same columns and data the one I have. [old table].

Comment: Then Muhammad Bro Above Mention Query work for you. It Will Create A New Table with your Desire Name And Also Insert data from Old Table

Comment: Yes, it works. thanks

Comment: Welcome Big Bro